# Fatal error in Unity CIL Linker - conflict with a System folder

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, linker, cil, il2cpp

guys.

So, the issue is, when I'm trying to make an IL2CPP build, I recieve this:

```
    Building Library\Bee\artifacts\WinPlayerBuildProgram\ManagedStripped failed with output:
C:\Programms\Unity\Editors\2021.2.11f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp\build\deploy\UnityLinker.exe @Library\Bee\artifacts\rsp\16461770786374037127.rsp
Fatal error in Unity CIL Linker
Mono.Linker.LinkerFatalErrorException: ILLink: error IL1005: System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11.SetDisplay(IntPtr): Error processing method 'System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11.SetDisplay(IntPtr)' in assembly 'System.Windows.Forms.dll'
 ---> Mono.Cecil.AssemblyResolutionException: Failed to resolve assembly: 'Mono.Posix, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Common.MissingMethodStubber.GetTypeModule(TypeReference type, IEnumerable`1 assemblies)
   at Unity.Linker.Steps.AddUnresolvedStubsStep.MarkAssemblyOfType(UnityLinkContext context, TypeReference type)
   at Unity.Linker.Steps.Marking.UnresolvedStubMarking.HandleUnresolvedType(TypeReference reference)
   at Unity.Linker.Steps.UnityMarkStep.HandleUnresolvedType(TypeReference reference)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference, DependencyInfo reason, IMemberDefinition sourceLocationMember)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody body)
   at Unity.Linker.Steps.UnityMarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody body)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method, DependencyInfo& reason)
   at Unity.Linker.Steps.UnityMarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method, DependencyInfo& reason)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessPrimaryQueue()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   at Unity.Linker.Steps.UnityMarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   at Unity.Linker.UnityPipeline.ProcessStep(LinkContext context, IStep step)
   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
   at Unity.Linker.UnityDriver.UnityRun(Boolean noProfilerAllowed, ILogger customLogger)
   at Unity.Linker.UnityDriver.RunDriverWithoutErrorHandling(ILogger customLogger, Boolean noProfilerAllowed)
   at Unity.Linker.UnityDriver.RunDriver()
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

I've been searching for an answer to this issue, but the fact it has a conflict with a System folder just kills me.

The Unity version is 2021.2.11f1, Mono build creates just fine.

Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Please look in your project if you have included `System.Windows.Forms.dll` in case not please add it.

Also I think that `System.Windows.Forms.dll` it's not suported by Unity so please search if you have any reference to it and replace it in that case.

I'm almost for sure that is an issue related to references maybe it fixes including all the `dlls` that are asked.

There is a package called [NuGetForUnity](https://github.com/GlitchEnzo/NuGetForUnity) that it might help.